# Multiple marker using android and google map

Tags: android, google-maps

In my application i want to add more than two markers in a Google map. Simply I can add one marker But i don't know how can i add multiple marker. Please tell me how can i do that.

Comment: do you mean multiple market bitmaps or just multiple instances of the same image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ItemizedOverlay to add mutiple layout. here has a sample code of ItemizedOverlay
`public class YourItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

```
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> myOverlays ;

public YourItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    yourOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    populate();
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay){
    yourOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return yourOverlays.get(i);
}

// Removes overlay item i
public void removeItem(int i){
    yourOverlays.remove(i);
    populate();
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return yourOverlays.size();
}


public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItem overlayItem) {
    yourOverlays.add(overlayItem);
    populate();
}


public void addOverlayItem(int lat, int lon, String title) {
    try {
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, title, null);
        addOverlayItem(overlayItem);    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String title = yourOverlays.get(index).getTitle();//display message when you touch your marker
    Toast.makeText(YourMapActivity.context, title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return super.onTap(index);
}
```

}`

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of having your `ItemizedOverlay` handle more than one marker, in your `size()` and `createItem()` methods. The `size()` method should return the number of markers you want and `createItem()` should return each `OverlayItem` based on the index.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk) demonstrating a map with four markers.

Comment: thanks for your link and it works...But i want to add a marker in my current location and others marker in different location. After detecting my current location, i can't add the marker...can you tell me why

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a low number of markers, you can also use the same overlay class multiple times. The basic map overlay is a lot easier to use, but after a certain point, it becomes very inefficient. I used two instances of a class for a current location and a flagged location as follows:

```
    overlayList = mapView.getOverlays();
    overlayList.clear();
    locationOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    pushpinOverlay = new MapOverlay();
```

Set the marker id for the png, the x offset, and the y offset here. (Functions coded in the MapOverlay class.)

```
    overlayList.add(locationOverlay);
    overlayList.add(pushpinOverlay);
```

Eventually invalidate map to force a redraw.

For two markers, it worked very nicely.